# Foreign key mismatch error in Django python

Tags: python, django, sqlite, model, migrate

I am new to Django and I am stuck on an error "Foreign key mismatch error" while migrating my project.
I have the following models in my project:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id=models.AutoField
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_desc=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_date=models.DateField()
    product_image=models.ImageField(upload_to="shop/images",default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

class User(models.Model):
    user_email=models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_email

class Student(models.Model):
    course=(
        ('MS','MS'),
        ('BS','BS')
    )
    student_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    student_roll=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_course=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=course)



class Order(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date=models.DateField()
    time=models.TimeField()
    price=models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)



class Teacher(models.Model):
    user_email=models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_email
```

I also created two more tables; **Person** and **Group** but I deleted these two tables later. Now, when I migrate my project using
**python manage.py makemigrations** and then
**python manage.py migrate**

I still get the error;

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "shop_membership" referencing "shop_person"**

So, what should I do now?

Comment: you can see the migration files in your `projects_dir/app_dir/migrations`. check the file and find one included Person and Group classes (the last one maybe). delete it, and make new migration

Comment: It really worked!! Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 8):

You should still have the migration file in which you have the `Person` and `Group` models. So you should delete the migration file that contains these models, but before deleting them be sure to revert the migrations if you have previously applied them.

To revert a migration, you can run:

```py
python manage.py migrate app_name xxxx_migration_before_the_one_you_want_to_un_apply
```

If you just started with the project, you can also revert all existing migrations by running:

```py
python manage.py migrate app_name -- zero
```

This will revert all the applied migrations after which you can simply delete all the migration files and then re-run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands to create all migrations in a single file and apply them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Membership model was referencing the Person model at some point. now that you have deleted the Person model, you might have to set that field to nulll (the foreign key to Person in Membership) or drop the Membership table altogether (please note you will lose the data).

Answer (score 0):

The error remains because you have an issue in one of the older migration files. The file(s) are being used to build up you database. Check the entire error message and see which migration file it refers to. Check if you have primary_key=True in your foreign key. Then remove the primary_key.